# Pass array to singleton (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

```
class MySingleton{
    static let shareInstance = MySingleton()
    private init() {}

    var myDetail = [Detail]() 
}

class DetailTableViewController {

     var expense = [Detail]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   ... put stuff in expense array ....


      MySingleton.shareInstance.myDetail = expense  //<--- doesn't work
      // error is "cannot assign value of type '[Detail]' to type [MySingleton.Detail]" 
  }
}
```

How do I copy an array to my MySingleton?
right now i just pass my array around my classes using segue

Comment: Put a complete *non-working* example up. My Playground edit of your example works fine, but obviously I had to add definition of `Detail` and take the assignment out of a non-working definition of a viewController...

Comment: It's likely that your expense array doesn't actually have anything in it...include the rest of your code. What you have so far works.

Comment: ...also, what is the error?

Comment: cannot assign value of type '[Detail]' to type [MySingleton.Detail]'

Comment: also these two classes are in different swift files

Comment: How is Detail defined? Sounds from your error like you are defining it twice, once locally to the singleton, once globally for the viewController...

Comment: Yes ! your right i forgot to delete Detail locally in my Singleton !!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you soooo much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error, it is likely you are defining `Detail` twice, once locally to the singleton, once globally for the viewController.